# Multiplexing seven segment display on AVR Atmega324A

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega

I've been stuck on this all day, I'm trying to create a count down timer using two seven segment displays. I want it to start at 20 and count down to zero. While 10< I only want to have the left display on(i.e no 0 in the tens place). I'm using an Atmega 324A. I have all of port C connected to the display segments and am using PIND0 to toggle between the two. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>


int main(void) {

    int prescale = (8000000/8)/1000-1;
    int digit = 1;
    uint8_t display;
    int seven_seg = {0x3F,0X06,0X5B,0X4F,0X66,0X6D,0X7D,0C07,0X7F,0X6F};
    // Set OC1 to output
    DDRD = (1<<0);
    DDRC = 0xFF;

    OCR1A = prescale;
    //clear counter on compare match
    TCCR1A = (0<<COM1A1) | (1<<COM1A0);
    //Set Prescale and CTC Mode
    TCCR1B =  (0<<CS12) | (1<<CS11) | (0<<CS10) | (0<<WGM13) | (1<<WGM12);


    while(1) {

            display++;
            if(display>50) display = 0;
            for (i = 250; i>0; i--){        
            PORTD ^= 0<<PIND0;
            PORTC = seven_seg[display%10];                
            PORTD ^= 1<<PIND0;
            _delay_ms(100);
            for (i = 250; i>0; i--){        
                PORTD ^= 1<<PIND0;
                PORTC = seven_seg[display/10];                
                PORTD ^= 0<<PIND0;
                _delay_ms(100);
             }
            }
        while((TIFR1 & (1<<OCF1A)) == 0) {}

        TIFR1 &= (1 << OCF1A);  

    }
}
```

All this does is set both displays to 0. Do I need another for loop to iterate through the seven_seg[] array while it's doing this? really not sure how to tackle this one. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your code is not correct. How can `seven_seg` store an array while it's only an `uint8_t`? And why don't use hexadecimal (or binary if your compiler supports that extension)? It'll be much harder to realize the segments using decimal. And please fix the indentation

Comment: For the question, why don't check if the MSD is 0 and display nothing?

Comment: If your compiler allows `int seven_seg = {0x3F,0X06,0X5B,0X4F,0X66,0X6D,0X7D,0C07,0X7F,0X6F};`, get a new compiler.   Suspect you want `int seven_seg[] /* add [] */ = {0x3F,0X06,0X5B,0X4F,0X66,0X6D,0X7D,0X07 /* not 0C07 */,0X7F,0X6F};`

Comment: i think you also want to use `uint8_t` instead of `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you make 2 big faults:

1. you don't use timer
2. you should separate display-driving-logic from value-generating-logic

best thing would be you split the tasks and plan how to implement this.

Task one: providing the data to display
Task two: transfering that data to a display friendly representation
Task three: the aktual displaying of that data

Task one is Easy. lets assume you want to display integers and you have three 7-seg-disps.
So task one is to provide some Data to display.

```
int16_t numberToDisplay = 234;
```

Task two is also not that hard. a display friendly representation would be one byte per display element.

```
#define NUM_7SEGS 3
volatile uint8_t dispData[NUM_7SEGS]; // volatile since it is be accassed by different contexts
```

now we need some mechanism that transfers the input value to the display data

```
void val2DispData(int16 val)
{
   uint8_t i;
   for(i=NUM_7SEGS; i; --i){
      uint8_t r = (uint8_t)(val%10);
      val /= 10
      dispData[i-1] = seven_seg[r];
   }
}
```

fine and now?

Task three is the most difficult one. we need someone who says the output what to do.
Since the want to multiplex the 3 display elements that means:

- deactivate the current display element
- put the data of the next digit to the outport
- activate the next display element
- wait a bit.

and this 4 steps we want to do very fast so that the observer does not recognize that only one element is active at a time.
since this is totally independent of the other program logic, we need to do this in "background".

your main program flow simply calls that function and the background timer ISR worrries about displaying.

So we have to set up a timer and call the switching of element data in its interrupt service routine. (for setting up timer and timer interupts please refer another tutorial)

```
// this have to be called cyclic from timer isr
// frequency is not that important but should be at 
// least NUM_7SEGS * 200 Hz to not look ugly
void cyclicDisplayTask()
{
  static uint8_t currentElement = 0;

  // disable all elements
  PORTD = 0;

  // put data on the port
  PORTC = dispData[currentElement]; // this is why the volatile is necessary. without the compiler would not notice that values may be changed by the main program flow

  // enable next element
  PORTD = (1<<currentElement);

  ++currentElement;
  if(currentElement>=NUM_7SEGS){
    currentElement = 0;
  }
}
```

of course you have to adapt the enabling of specific display elements to your hardware.

please also note that you may youse a transistor to drive the element. an AVR port pin is strong enogh to drive a single segment but the other side that drives the common anodes/cathodes of the segment may be overload. This of course depends on the leds within the segments. if this are low current leds (~2mA) it is ok.